# Solving the equation $\cos(x) \cdot \cosh (x) + 1 = 0$

Tags: trigonometry, transcendental-equations

$$\cos(x) \cdot \cosh (x) + 1 = 0$$

Sorry I am a software developer and I have forgotten this part of mathematics! What is the value of $x$ in the above equation?

I need the steps to solve the equation like school level where we solve the equation!

Rather can we simplify the equation?

Comment: Numerical solutions can be given, but I seriously doubt there are any closed form solutions in x.

Comment: Actually I need to find value of x . What do you mean numberical solutions can be given ? Can you explain how to solve the equation with steps ?

Comment: There are multiple solutions, and by numerical solutions, I mean solutions that can be approximated by a finite decimal expansion, but can not be given in terms of elementary functions, for example here is one solution $x=10.9955407348...$, also note that if $x_1$ is a solution then $-x_1$ will also be a solution because $\cos(x)\cosh(x)$ is an even function.

Comment: Ethan - I know the value of x ! I understand what you are trying to say :) But I need the steps to find the value of x. I need the steps :) It would be really helpful if you explain how to solve the equation !

Comment: There are no specific "steps" to finding a solution to this equation, it can not be algebraically manipulated so that a series of closed form solutions can be found, it can however be approximated by various methods, for example newtons method is one.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Ccos%28x%29+%5Ccdot+%5Ccosh+%28x%29+%2B+1+%3D+0

Answer (score 1):

Taking  the multivalued $\cos^{-1}(z)$ on both sides and using [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) gives:

$$\cos(z)\cosh(z)+1=0\iff z=\underbrace{\left\{\left(2k+\frac12\right)\pi+,\left(2k+\frac32\right)\pi-\right\}}_ai\ln\left(1+\frac2{ie^x-1}\right)\implies z_k=a+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\pm i)^n\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\frac{\ln^n\left(\frac2{ie^w-1}+1\right)}{n!}\right|_a$$

All roots are $\pm iz_k,\pm z_k,k\in\Bbb N$. A [Stirling S1 $S_n^{(m)}$ expansion](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/23/02/0001/) gives:

$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\frac{\ln^n\left(\frac2{ie^w-1}+1\right)}{n!}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{2^{m+n}S_{m+n}^{(n)}}{(m+n)!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}(i e^w-1)^{n+m}$$

Next, use a [Stirling S2 $s_n^{(m)}$ expansion](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Exp/20/02/0002/):

$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}(i e^w-1)^{-m} =\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}e^{wj}s_{n-1}^{(j)}(-1)^j\left(e^w+i\right)^{-j-m}\frac{\Gamma(j+m)}{\Gamma(m)}$$

Therefore:

$$\bbox[4px,border:6px ridge cyan]{\cos(z)\cosh(z)+1=0\implies z_k= e^\frac{\pi ic}2\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi+ e^\frac{\pi ic}2\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1} ^m\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^j2^m i^{\pm n-m} e^{\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi j} S_m^{(n)}s_{n-1}^{(j)}\Gamma(j+m)}{\left(e^{\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi}+i\right)^{j+m}\Gamma(m)m!}}$$

where $0\ne k\in\Bbb N;c=1,\dots,4$ and even $k$ takes $+$ while odd $k$ takes $-$. For $c=0$, [$z_2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5B%282%2B1%2F2%29%CF%80%2Bsum%5Bsum%5Bsum%5B2%5E%28m%2Bn%29%2F%28m%2Bn%29%21+StirlingS1%5Bm%2Bn%2C+n%5D+E%5E%28j+%282%2B1%2F2%29%CF%80%29+StirlingS2%5Bn-1%2Cj%5D+i%5E%28-%28m%2Bn%29%2B1+n%29%28+exp%28%282*1%2B1%2F2%29%CF%80%29%2Bi%29%5E%28-j-%28m%2Bn%29%29+%28-1%29%5Ej+%CE%93%28j%2Bm%2Bn%29%2F%CE%93%28m%2Bn%29%2C+%7Bj%2C0%2C30-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C30%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C30%7D%5D%2C10%5D) and [$z_3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%283%2B1%2F2%29%CF%80%2BN%5Bsum%5Bsum%5Bsum%5B2.0%5E%28m%2Bn%29%2F%28m%2Bn%29%21+StirlingS1%5Bm%2Bn%2C+n%5D+E%5E%28j+%283%2B1%2F2%29%CF%80%29+StirlingS2%5Bn-1%2Cj%5D+i%5E%28-%28m%2Bn%29-1+n%29%28+exp%28%283%2B1%2F2%29%CF%80%29%2Bi%29%5E%28-j-%28m%2Bn%29%29+%28-1%29%5Ej+%CE%93%28j%2Bm%2Bn%29%2F%CE%93%28m%2Bn%29%2C+%7Bj%2C0%2C30-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C30%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C30%7D%5D%2C10%5D), [precisely](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%283%2B1%2F2%29%CF%80-0.0000335527+), [match](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cos%28x%29cosh%28x%29%2B1%3D0) decimal solutions to the equation.

Comment: Maybe someone can manipulate the series to get a double sum or integral representation?

Comment: One can put the equation in the form $aw^m+bw^n+cw=d$ or perhaps $w=-1+w^{-i}(aw-1)$ to get a double sum or a single sum/integral over a hypergeometric function

Answer (score 0):

One method of going about this would be to use the exponential form of cosh(x):

$cosh(x)=\frac{1+e^{2x}}{2e^x}$

Multiplying the cosine in and adding in 1, you get:

$\frac{cos(x)+cos(x)e^{2x}+2e^x}{2e^x}$

Which allows you to eliminate the divisor:

$cos(x)+cos(x)e^{2x}+2e^x=0$

An alternative method which contains a constant involves ignoring the negative component of $e^-x$, resulting in:

$cos(x)(e^x+e^{-x})=-2$

As x tends towards larger and larger numbers, the roots more closely line up with cos(x). The difference between the roots of cos(x) and your equation are as follows:

$1.875-\frac{\pi}{2}=.304,4.694-\frac{3\pi}{2}=.018,7.855-\frac{5\pi}{2}=.001$